# how to link home-brew python with Xcode or sublime for development on mac

Tags: python, xcode, macos, sublimetext3, homebrew

i'm trying to link home brew version of python 2.7.13 on Xcode or even Sublime text for external build system however when ever i try to run it, it never goes through. I have seen numerous videos and posts but i can't find a solution.I have both python 2.7.13 and python 3.6 install through home-brew.If there is anything that i forgot to mention please let me know.I've been on it for a few weeks now i don't know where I'm i wrong.I'm not sure about the python path which i should provide for python 2.7 its seems to me as like should i do usr/local/Cellar...2.7/Version/Python or /usr/local/bin/python(shown in terminal)

```
# This is what my .bash_profile looks like
 export EDITOR='subl -w'
 # Setting PATH for Python 2.7
 # The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
 export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
 [[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc
 source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:$PATH
source /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualwrapper.sh
```

I'm fairly new and i'm trying to learn python.

Comment: i came up with he solution after finding some more information and i got to know:

1) Xcode doesn't support interactive console for Python as of now.

2) To use active console in sublime i downloaded SublimeREPL through package control and after downloading it and going to Sublime Text menu
    Prefrences>Browse Packages>SublimeREPL>Config>Python>  main.sublime-menu.

Comment: Open this main.sublime-menu file and make the following changes:
1) In the block starting form Command : ""command": "repl_open" got to "cmd": [*"/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6"**, "-u",**"-i"**, "$file_basename"], make the changes for where the python is located in my case i downloaded it from Home-brew and add "-i" command as above and save the file by name such as REPL(Python Version).
Now go to ST3 build new system and make the put this in the file:

Comment: Now go to ST3> Tools> Build System> New Build System, build new system and put this in the file. Put this in the file 
{
    "target": "run_existing_window_command",
    "id": "repl_python_run",
    "file": "/Users/nipunkaushik/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main3.6.sublime-menu"
}
Which means linking the file we made earlier to the build system for a specific python version and in my case its 3.6.

Comment: The file mentioned in the above comment is saved as **Main3.6.sublime-menu** to avoid any confusion.
I made two files in first case each for Python 2.7 and 3.6 and accordingly two build systems REPL2.7 and REPL3.6 which works perfect when i tried.